# Enviar int y string por Serial C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Estoy desarrollando un simulador para Asseto Corsa. Tengo una API que me saca la telemetría de la memoria compartida del juego, pero necesito enviar algunos de esos datos por serial(USB) para captarlos con un Arduino y procesarlos.
Tengo el código de la API(que adjunto mas abajo) y el de Arduino no es problema, el problema es como enviar los datos que necesito(ints y strings) a través del puerto serie.
He visto que hay una libreria(SerialPort) pero está programada en C++, y todo lo que he encontrado sobre C#, no me ha funcionado, ya que el Arduino no recibe nada.

```
using AssettoCorsaSharedMemory;
using System;
using System.IO.Ports;
using System.Threading;


namespace ConsoleApplication1
{

public class Program
{

static bool _continue;
static SerialPort _serialPort;

public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    AssettoCorsa ac = new AssettoCorsa();
    ac.StaticInfoInterval = 5000; // Get StaticInfo updates ever 5 seconds
    ac.StaticInfoUpdated += ac_StaticInfoUpdated; // Add event listener for StaticInfo
    ac.PhysicsUpdated += ac_PhysicsUpdated; //  Add event listener for Physics
    ac.Start(); // Connect to shared memory and start interval timers 

    Console.ReadKey();

    string name;
    string message;
    StringComparer stringComparer = StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase;
    Thread readThread = new Thread(Read);

    // Create a new SerialPort object with default settings.
    _serialPort = new SerialPort();

    // Allow the user to set the appropriate properties.
    _serialPort.PortName = SetPortName(_serialPort.PortName);
    _serialPort.BaudRate = SetPortBaudRate(_serialPort.BaudRate);
    _serialPort.Parity = SetPortParity(_serialPort.Parity);
    _serialPort.DataBits = SetPortDataBits(_serialPort.DataBits);
    _serialPort.StopBits = SetPortStopBits(_serialPort.StopBits);
    _serialPort.Handshake = SetPortHandshake(_serialPort.Handshake);

    // Set the read/write timeouts
    _serialPort.ReadTimeout = 500;
    _serialPort.WriteTimeout = 500;

    _serialPort.Open();
    _continue = true;
    readThread.Start();

    Console.Write("Name: ");
    name = Console.ReadLine();

    Console.WriteLine("Type QUIT to exit");

    while (_continue)
    {
        message = Console.ReadLine();

        if (stringComparer.Equals("quit", message))
        {
            _continue = false;
        }
        else
        {
            _serialPort.WriteLine(
                String.Format("<{0}>: {1}", name, message));
        }
    }

    readThread.Join();
    _serialPort.Close();

}

public static void Read()
{
    while (_continue)
    {
        try
        {
            string message = _serialPort.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine(message);
        }
        catch (TimeoutException) { }
    }
}
public static string SetPortName(string defaultPortName)
{
    string portName;

    Console.WriteLine("Available Ports:");
    foreach (string s in SerialPort.GetPortNames())
    {
        Console.WriteLine("   {0}", s);
    }

    Console.Write("Enter COM port value (Default: {0}): ", defaultPortName);
    portName = Console.ReadLine();

    if (portName == "" || !(portName.ToLower()).StartsWith("com"))
    {
        portName = defaultPortName;
    }
    return portName;
}
public static int SetPortBaudRate(int defaultPortBaudRate)
{
    string baudRate;

    Console.Write("Baud Rate(default:{0}): ", defaultPortBaudRate);
    baudRate = Console.ReadLine();

    if (baudRate == "")
    {
        baudRate = defaultPortBaudRate.ToString();
    }

    return int.Parse(baudRate);
}
public static Parity SetPortParity(Parity defaultPortParity)
{
    string parity;

    Console.WriteLine("Available Parity options:");
    foreach (string s in Enum.GetNames(typeof(Parity)))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("   {0}", s);
    }

    Console.Write("Enter Parity value (Default: {0}):", defaultPortParity.ToString(), true);
    parity = Console.ReadLine();

    if (parity == "")
    {
        parity = defaultPortParity.ToString();
    }

    return (Parity)Enum.Parse(typeof(Parity), parity, true);
}
public static int SetPortDataBits(int defaultPortDataBits)
{
    string dataBits;

    Console.Write("Enter DataBits value (Default: {0}): ", defaultPortDataBits);
    dataBits = Console.ReadLine();

    if (dataBits == "")
    {
        dataBits = defaultPortDataBits.ToString();
    }

    return int.Parse(dataBits.ToUpperInvariant());
}
public static StopBits SetPortStopBits(StopBits defaultPortStopBits)
{
    string stopBits;

    Console.WriteLine("Available StopBits options:");
    foreach (string s in Enum.GetNames(typeof(StopBits)))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("   {0}", s);
    }

    Console.Write("Enter StopBits value (None is not supported and \n" +
     "raises an ArgumentOutOfRangeException. \n (Default: {0}):", defaultPortStopBits.ToString());
    stopBits = Console.ReadLine();

    if (stopBits == "")
    {
        stopBits = defaultPortStopBits.ToString();
    }

    return (StopBits)Enum.Parse(typeof(StopBits), stopBits, true);
}
public static Handshake SetPortHandshake(Handshake defaultPortHandshake)
{
    string handshake;

    Console.WriteLine("Available Handshake options:");
    foreach (string s in Enum.GetNames(typeof(Handshake)))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("   {0}", s);
    }

    Console.Write("Enter Handshake value (Default: {0}):", defaultPortHandshake.ToString());
    handshake = Console.ReadLine();

    if (handshake == "")
    {
        handshake = defaultPortHandshake.ToString();
    }

    return (Handshake)Enum.Parse(typeof(Handshake), handshake, true);
}

static void ac_StaticInfoUpdated(object sender, StaticInfoEventArgs e)
{
  /*Console.WriteLine("StaticInfo");
    Console.WriteLine("  Car Model: " + e.StaticInfo.CarModel);
    Console.WriteLine("  Track:     " + e.StaticInfo.Track);
    Console.WriteLine("  Max RPM:   " + e.StaticInfo.MaxRpm);*/
}
static void ac_PhysicsUpdated(object sender, PhysicsEventArgs e)
{
    String gea = "N";
    switch (e.Physics.Gear)
    {
        case 0:
            gea = "R";
            break;
        case 1:
            gea = "N";
            break;
        case 2:
            gea = "1";
            break;
        case 3:
            gea = "2";
            break;
        case 4:
            gea = "3";
            break;
        case 5:
            gea = "4";
            break;
        case 6:
            gea = "5";
            break;
        case 7:
            gea = "6";
            break;
    }

    Console.WriteLine("  Rpms  " + e.Physics.Rpms + "   Gear  " + gea);

    string str = Convert.ToString(e.Physics.Rpms);
    _serialPort.Write(str);

}
}
```

Comment: Has visto esta documentación? https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.io.ports.serialport(v=vs.110).aspx Aunque es fácil que para enviar un dato, lo tengas que pasar a un array de bytes y para recibir lo mismo, recibirás un array de bytes

Comment: Bienvenido a [es.so]! Te recomiendo que hagas el [tour] y así ganar tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/84/informed). Lee [ask] y [¿sobre qué temas puedo preguntar aquí?](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) para aprender a realizar una buena pregunta

Comment: C# como te han dicho tiene su propia libreria para comunicación serie. Si tienes algun problema con ella deberías ser mas específico con el código que has probado y el problema que tienes con el.

Comment: @PabloSimonDiEstefano He añadido esa libreria, pero ahora me dice que solo puede haber una función Main en el programa, y el problema es que solo tengo una funcion Main, no entiendo porque me devuelve ese error.